# Google Tag Manager prevents Turbolinks from working

Tags: google-tag-manager, turbolinks

I'm trying to use Turbolinks in conjunction with Google Tag Manager. The tags will fire just fine on page navigation.
However, I'm getting a **full page reload** every time unless the following script is removed:

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ID');
```

Somehow, Google Tag Manager seems to mess with the Turbolinks functionality (we use it to track outlinks).
Has anybody figured out how to get page swapping while still keeping Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was that the "Clicks - Just Links" trigger condition was too broad and prevented other event listeners like the Turbolinks one from firing.

I excluded same-site links by adding a condition "`Click URL` starts with `http`" to the GTM trigger.